# How to stop a wireshark capture using tshark command

Tags: windows, cmd, capture, tshark

I am capturing traces for a SIP call by executing a tshark command on windows command prompt. I need to know a command to stop the trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [-a flag](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html#a-capture-autostop-condition) to specify an auto-stop condition when you run it.